# Trim down unused XP roles in a sitecore 9.0.1 XP scaled setup hosted in Azure PaaS

Tags: paas, setup

What is the recommended way to trim down the XP roles in a XP Scaled setup (Sitecore 9.0.1) that are not being used by the business. Currently we are using only XM features, so we thought of cutting down some costs.

Step 1. Identify the web apps that needs to be cut down (webapps like ma-ops, ma-rep, xc-collect)
Step 2. Identify the Azure SQL Databases (reporting, processing)

Is there a complete guide that sitecore offers on this? Can anyone share your experience. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am looking for how I can trim down / downscale few XP roles that are not in use (like xDB, Reporting, Processing, MA, etc). I will start this with lower envs. My site is live with 50+ websites.

Comment: If you are only using XM features, maybe consider rolling out an XM Environment and pulling all your content into that?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Sitecore 9.0 topologies](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0043375) to get a glimpse on how XM is different from XP.

From there you'll need to turn off Analytics via Sitecore configurations.

Otherwise it would constantly complain on not getting response from Analytics parts (f.e. xConnect) as well as throw exceptions on un-functional Analytic-related Apps shown in the Dashboard.

Shortly after you'll see zero load on some resources (f.e. *aggregation / Reporting / Processing / xConnect*) if you completely disabled analytics.

Those resources are the services/candidates for assassinations.

You would also see a drop in Azure SQL usage, so potentially could lower the tier used for elastic pool.